# Find an expectation of normal random variable

Tags: probability, expected-value

How can I find an expectation of random variable $\xi \sim \mathcal{N}(a,1)$, where $a$ is random variable: $a \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2),\quad  \sigma = \text{constant}$ ?

Comment: It seems to me that I have to use conditional density $p(x,a) = p(x|a=y)*p(a=y)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you already learned that $Y = X + Z$ follows $\mathcal{N}(\nu_1+\nu_2, \sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2)$ if $X\sim \mathcal{N}(\nu_1, \sigma_1^2)$, $Z\sim \mathcal{N}(\nu_2, \sigma_2^2)$, and $X$ and $Z$ are independent.

In your question,$\xi \sim \mathcal{N}(a,1)$ conditional on $a$, so $\xi$ can be written as
$$\xi = a + \epsilon$$ 
with  $a \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$ and  $\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$.Obviousely, for a given $a$, $\xi \sim \mathcal{N}(a,1)$. The unconditional $\xi$ is distributed as:
$$\xi \sim \mathcal{N}(0+0,\sigma^2+1)$$
So $E(\xi) = 0$.

Another solution is

$$E(\xi) = E_a(E_{\xi|a}(\xi)) = E(a) = 0$$

Comment: Thnx a lot, there is another question how can I find prob that $\xi$ less than 1?

Comment: You need to know $\sigma^2$. Then $1/\sigma$ is Z value in standard normal. I believe you can find the answer.

Comment: I'm not fluent in this theme, and don't completely understand. How Z-score help to find $P(\xi <1)$?

Comment: pnorm(1, 0, $\sigma^2$) in R can give you the answer. It is $\int_{-\infty}^{\frac 1\sigma} f(x) dx$, where $f(x) = \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}$ pdf of N(0,1)

Comment: Sorry for being annoying, but I need a little bit more explanation, I have a random variable with expectation which is random variable, how density looks like? Could you give me lecture notes or similar tasks with solutions?

Comment: There some thoughts $P(\xi < 1) = \sum_{k = -\infty}^{+\infty} P(\xi-a<k, a<1-k) $ And so forth